# Passing Xml data through query string having special characters in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, xml

I want to send Title from XML file to another page through query string. My titles may Contain
"&". I know I have to encode it, But how can I do it in aspx page. I don't want to do it from code behind.

```
<a href="NewsByTitle.aspx?title=<%#XPath("title")%>"
```

Please Help!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Check HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode.

[doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/w3te6wfz.aspx)

```
<a href="NewsByTitle.aspx?title=<%#HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode(XPath("title"))%>"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Eldar, I tried this but I get the following error                                                                       The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Check, please, adding ToString() call to XPath("title").ToString().
This return string of an object

Comment: Not sure if the ToString() fixed the error in the comment, but in this cases, I think you should use HttpUtility.UrlEncode and not HtmlEncode. It's different.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try disabling Request Validation.

set this on page directive

```
 <%@ Page validateRequest="false" %>
```

and following under system.web inside web.config

```
 <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```